# Inbound and Outbound calls question

Tags: apex, api, callout, rest, sync

Can we make an outbound REST SYNC call when receiving an inbound REST call?
External system 1 calls Salesforce
Salesforce calls External System 2
Salesforce returns to external system 1 the answer of External System 2

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If neither External System 1 or External System 2 are Salesforce, this is possible, assuming all the rules for callouts are followed (no callout after DML, 6MB max callout size, 120 second max timeout, etc). Salesforce cannot call itself recursively from a callout, which is detected by a special header that Salesforce adds to callouts to detect and prevent potentially infinite recursion.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks! I do remember now that the problem are between SF orgs.